# Eclipse error on launching

Tags: java, eclipse

I have installed eclipse for andriod but when I launch it, I am getting error in the eclipse executable launcher that was unable to locate its companion shared library where
my eclipse.ini file is

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm “C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\javaw.exe” 
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-Declipse.buildId=v21.1.0-569685
```

It was working some days before but after upgrading jdk it is not working

Comment: You appear to have a 64 bit Java with 32 bit Eclipse. They must both be either 32 bit or 64 bit.

Comment: sorry greg ,both java and eclipse are of 32 bit

Comment: Things in 'C:\Program Files' are normally 64 bit, it would be 'C:\Program Files (x86)' for 32 bit.

Comment: there is no folder  "C:\Program Files (x86)' in c drive

Comment: I think the opposite is correct @greg-449 ..Things in 'C:\Program Files' are normally 32 bit, it would be 'C:\Program Files (x86)' for 64 bit.

Comment: @Lal See https://superuser.com/questions/299543/what-is-the-difference-between-program-files-and-program-files-x86

Comment: See this [link](http://superuser.com/questions/442246/why-does-64-bit-windows-need-a-separate-program-files-x86-folder) @greg-449

Comment: @Lal the first line of the link you have referenced: "I know that on a 64-bit version of Windows the "Program Files" folder is for 64-bit programs and the "Program Files (x86)" folder is for 32-bit programs, but why is this even necessary?"